# WIX - How to launch readme and exe at the end of the installation

Tags: wix

I've read the WIX instructions [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html):

However, I want to launch the readme and the application which doesn't appear to be supported.  Also the solution provided by the WIX documentation does not automatically check the option on the final screen.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample code will help you to launch exe or open .txt file after MSI Install.
You can do some hacks and add it to UI. If launch box is checked it will launch specific exe or do action whichever you state there.

Below one without any UI launch whiechever exe you provide it to launch.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
         <Custom Action='LaunchInstalledExe' After='InstallFinalize'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="LaunchInstalledExe"
         FileKey="ExeFile"
         ExeCommand="" 
         Execute="immediate" 
         Impersonate="yes" 
         Return="asyncNoWait" />
```