# Checkbox on Wix bootsrapper success window

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield, wix3.7, wix3.8

I am working with `wix 4.0` and my main idea is to make checkbox on last installation window in `wix bootsrapper`. When user select the checkbox and press close button , the file(word Document) will be launched. But I don't found the information on how can i do it with the file. I tried set variable on `bundle.wxs`

```
<Variable Name="launchTarget"  Value="Path\to\file.docx"/>
```

but this option just makes aditional button on success window and works well... but this is not my goal.

I already create checkbox on `theme.xml` file by this :

```
<Checkbox Name="DoTest" X="70" Y="-22" Width="120" Height="30" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">Run Document</Checkbox>
```

And set value to 1 on `bundle.wxs` like this :

```
<Variable Name="DoTest"  Value="1"/>
```

And finally i got this not worked properly variant: 
[image]

Maybe someone can help me please with this ? Then checkbox are ticked the `.docx` file will launch. If needed I can paste full bundle code below.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run a custom action if the checkbox variable (DoTest) has been set. This is very similar to [launching a readme at the end of your install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057081/wix-how-to-launch-readme-and-exe-at-the-end-of-the-installation).